# loop problem within a statement

Tags: php, mysql, tags

i hope someone can help about to scream!

basically I am trying to do a few things with the statement below;

First i want to check if the user id exists in member_categories_position. 
If it Does i want then to exclude all entries from the second statement  where member_id equals all results from the first statement
the third statement is the else statement that displays if the member_id is not present in the member_categories position.

PROBLEM - the result from the first system loops fine, however when i try and insert into the second statement (!='$memid') is produces no results and has no effect. I think the problem is that $memid is a looped result.

How do i get the second statement to say that any member_id that is in member_categories_position will not show in that statement?

```
$sql2 = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM member_categories_position a 
    JOIN member_users b 
        ON b.id = a.member_id";

$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
{
    $memid = "".$row['member_id']."";   
}

if(mysql_num_rows($rs2) != 0)
{
    $new= "
        SELECT * 
        FROM member_categories 
        JOIN member_users 
            ON member_categories.member_id=member_users.id 
        JOIN member_config 
            ON member_categories.member_id=member_config.member_id 
        WHERE 
            member_categories.categories='$category' 
            AND member_categories.member_id !='$field'  
        GROUP BY member_config.member_id  
        ORDER BY RAND() limit 0,42";

    $rs = mysql_query($new);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
    {
        echo "result excluding member ids from the first statement";
    }
    echo "<div class=\"clear\"></div>";
}
else
{

    $new= "
        SELECT * 
        FROM member_categories 
        JOIN member_users 
            ON member_categories.member_id=member_users.id 
        JOIN member_config 
            ON member_categories.member_id=member_config.member_id 
        WHERE
            member_categories.categories='$category' 
        GROUP BY member_config.member_id  
        ORDER BY RAND() limit 0,42";

    $rs = mysql_query($new);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
    {
        echo "Result with all member ids";
    }
    echo "<div class=\"clear\"></div>";

}  } <-- (second is a stray from original post)
```

Comment: Please edit your above code to use proper indentation - it'll make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Where do $field and $category get their values from?

Comment: $field should be $memid and $category is a $_REQUEST that works fine that is placed above this coding.

Comment: Would also be a wise idea to separate your business/database logic from your presentation logic.

Comment: thanks jball, not really following you though barfoon sorry!

Answer (score 0):

$memid is not in scope since it appears to be defined inside the loop.  Try defining $memid =  ''; at the top of your script.. like this.

```
$memid =  '';
$sql2 = "
         SELECT *
```

That way it will be defined when you use it below..

Comment: $memid is defined from the first statement, it is the results that check if the member id exists in member_categories_position, this then determines the results that should be displayed